# DatePicker in MetroUI CSS falls behind panels

Tags: jquery, css

Trying to get the Datepicker to stop falling behind the panels.
I have already opened a post on their site as well.

```
Code is in the fiddler
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c9LhLdLg/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy fix to this.

```
jsfiddle.net/c9LhLdLg/3/
```

Comment: Actually the panels are no longer functional. Seems setting z to 0 allows them to work again.